# Execute different SQL based on timerange

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I have around five queries which produce the same kind of output and the only difference is that they fetch data from separate tables like Hourly table, Daily table, Weekly table.

Now I want to write a query which produces outputs from one of the five tables, based on the user's input.  E.g.

```
IF THE USER PROVIDED TIMERANGE IS GREATER THAN 1 AND LESS THAN 24 HRS 
  THEN EXTRACT FROM HOURLY TABLE--i.e. execute 1st query 
IF THE USER PROVIDED TIMERANGE IS GREATER THAN 24 AND LESS THAN 7 DAYS
  THEN EXTRACT FROM DAILY TABLE-- i.e. execute 2nd query
```

..... and so forth

Note : All five queries return the same type of output.  That is, the projection of the select clause is the same for all the queries.

Can this be done via a single SQL statement ( maybe using union) or do I need to write a PL/SQL for this?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with the UNION ALL operator:

```
select * from hourly_table
where (&&user_end_date - &&user_start_day) < 1
union all
select * from weekly_table
where (&&user_end_date - &&user_start_day) between 1 and 7
union all
select * from monthly_table
where &&user_end_date <= add_months(&&user_start_day, 1)
union all
select * from yearly_table
where &&user_end_date <= add_months(&&user_start_day, 12)
union all
select * from whatever_table
where &&user_end_date > add_months(&&user_start_day, 12)
```

I have used the SQL*Plus syntax for substitution variables; you may need to change this to fit whatever client you are using to run the query.

Answer (score 0):

CASE.. WHEN might help

```
select 
CASE ConditionVar
  WHEN Val1 THEN Query1 
  WHEN Val2 THeN Query2
  ELSE QUERY3
END as myresult
from my_tables (dual in case no need of table);
```

Detailed explanation of case 
http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php

Alternative syntax, this might be more useful in your case

```
select 
CASE 
   WHEN condition1 THEN Query1 
   WHEN condition2 THeN Query2
   ELSE QUERY3
END as myresult
from my_tables (dual in case no need of table);
```

Comment: The OP wants to change the *table* they select from on the basis of the user input.

Comment: I dont think so it will work when a query returns multiple rows. because Case statement will return scalar value

Comment: @APC, Table can be changed with a little modification in from column at the end (fom a, b,c and in case we can return a.col or b.col), but I will agree that it is not a clean way. Moreover we will not be able to select more than 1 col. Solution you suggested looks more elegant.

Comment: @ShitalBumb You are right that we cannot return more than one column. We can have a workaround by concatenating the column values which can be separated out in code. But yes, this is not perfect solution, so if there is an alternate solution which solves the problem, you should go for that